# Excel Date/Time formatting AM vs PM error

Tags: excel, date, time

I am using Windward to generate a report with readable dates. Winward uses **Excel date/time formatting** for formatting, however I am experiencing an issue when formatting a date/time within the 12th hour (eg 12:30) showing as AM rather than PM.

Are my Excel input/output date/time format strings incorrect?

Input format

```
yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S
```

Output format

```
dd MMM yyyy h:mm AM/PM
```

Examples

`2016-11-24 00:15:00.0` evaluates to `24 Nov 2016 12:15 AM` ***OK***

`2016-11-25 12:15:00.0` evaluates to `25 Nov 2016 12:15 AM` ***WRONG***

`2016-11-26 13:15:00.0` evaluates to `26 Nov 2016 1:15 PM` ***OK***

Comment: As is with most questions I've asked on SO, the solution beheld itself moments after submitting the question, sigh.

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't to do with the Excel date/time format strings. Windward uses java's `SimpleDateFormat` class to evaluate date inputs and `Excel Date Formatting` to output the formatted date. The following input format works correctly.

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S
```

As per [oracle documentation here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html://)

> **Letter    Date or Time Component Presentation    Examples**
>
> H Hour in day (0-23)  Number  0
>
> h Hour in am/pm (1-12)    Number  12